# Django contact form not showning the sender's email

Tags: django, forms, email

I am working on a contact form that sends emails, when I try sending emails, both the sender and the receiver is of same value (eg. `example@gmail.com`). kindly help out

here is my settings.py file

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

views.py

```
    def Contacts(request):
       if request.method == "POST":
          message_name = request.POST.get('message-name')
          message_subject = request.POST.get('message-subject')
          from_email = request.POST.get('from-email')
          message = request.POST.get('message')

      send_mail(
         message_subject,
         message,
         from_email,
         ['example@gmail.com'],
         fail_silently=False,
      )
      return render(request, 'Contacts/index.html', {'message_subject':message_subject})
   else:
      return render(request, 'Contacts/index.html', {})
```

my html form

```
          <form method="post" action="{% url 'Contacts' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="fname">First Name *</label>
          <input class="required form-control" id="message-name" name="message-name" placeholder="First Name&nbsp;*" type="text" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="lname">Last Name *</label>
          <input class="required form-control" id="message-lname" name="message-lname" placeholder="Last Name&nbsp;*" type="text" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="contactEmail">Email *</label>
          <input class="required form-control h5-email" id="from-email" name="from-email" placeholder="Email&nbsp;*" type="text" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="contactPhone">Subject *</label>
          <input class="required form-control h5-phone" id="message-subject" name="message-subject" placeholder="Subject&nbsp;*" type="text" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="comment">Type your message here</label>
          <textarea class="required form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Type your message here&nbsp;*" rows="6" required="required"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-accent" type="submit">Submit</button>  
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's not showing? aren't you taking the sender's email as input in the form how do you expect your page to show it beforehand? Also you are using the input email as the from email which won't work necessarily as the input email might not be your email that you have set in `EMAIL_HOST_USER`

Comment: the EMAIL_HOST_USER is the email where the messages are sent to,problem is, when someone sends a message, both the receiver and sender's email appear as the EMAIL_HOST_USER, the sender's email does not appear.

Comment: The email host user is the sender! You cannot send emails from email addresses that don't belong to you!!

Comment: Oh!, thanks for the clarification, i thought EMAIL_HOST_USER is the receiver's email, so how do get other people to send me emails without having to manually add their email addresses in the EMAIL_HOST_USER

Comment: It is not possible, You can simply put an anchor tag with a `mailto:email@example.com` in the href to have them click it and have it open a default mail app of the user. You can add various parameters to the url to have the subject, body etc. preset for the user.

Comment: Oh!, thank you so much.

Comment: so to be able to receive emails when they're sent to me, i have to use mail service APIs?

Comment: @Henry Pay attention when submitting a question to not share your email